# Have ButtonImage point to user finger when it is pressed (Kotlin and android studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, rotation, android-view

I have a image button that when pressed I want it to point to the users finger (etc. like how a character looks at the users mouse in a video game). however It is not working and it dose not track the finger properly. I think it has something to do with my logic but im not sure.

here is my code:

```
findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.leftButton).setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
    //Will happen when image is pressed other wise event is set to false
    when (motionEvent.action){
        //change opacity of nob direction image when user holds finger on image
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {

           //remove directional image (not the image moving)
           findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.leftButtonDerection).alpha = 0.0f

           //get y and x value of finger
           val x: Float = motionEvent.x
           val y: Float = motionEvent.y

           //find x and y value for nob image (this is where I think the problem is)
           val nobCenterX = (findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.leftButton).x + findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.leftButton).width) / 2
           val nobCenterY = (findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.leftButton).y + findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.leftButton).height) / 2

           //calculate angle from finger to nob point
           val angle = Math.toDegrees(atan2(y - nobCenterY, x - nobCenterX).toDouble())

           //apply angle to nob image rotation
           findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.leftButton).rotation = angle.toFloat()
       }
       //when user lets go or the hold action is stopped
       //it will reset the opacity of the direction image
       MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
           findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.leftButtonDerection).alpha = 1.0f
           findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.leftButton).rotation = 0f
       }
   }
   false
}
```

output from code:
[image: Screen capture]

What i want is for the image to be able to do a full 360 so it can follow the finger at any position once pressed.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is where you think it is, the button center coordinates are independent of the touch coordinates.

```
val nobCenterX = width / 2
val nobCenterY = height / 2
```

The second problem is that you are rotating the same view that you are listening for touch events on, this will result in a jittery rotation. I suggest that you listen for touch events on your inner view (`leftButtonDerection`) and rotate the outer one (`leftButton`).